# Custom frequency in fpp package

Tags: time-series, frequency, arima, forecast

Here is my data,

```
my_df <- data.frame(some_data = sample(1:100, 21, replace=T))
```

I would like to use this time series with `ARIMA` from `fpp` package and state that frequency/period is 3. Previously, with `forecast` package it was easy, I could you use `ts(., frequency = 3)`, but I am not sure how to do it with `fpp`.

Answer (score 1):

The `fpp` package simply contains data not functions. It depends on the `forecast` package for all modelling. So you can use `ts(my_df$some_data, frequency=3)` as usual.